# existence of smooth vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $M^n$ be a smooth orientable maniofold.
Suppose $f\colon M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function such that $df\neq 0$ 
at each point of $M$. Show that there exists a smooth vector field $V$ on $M$ so that $df(V)\leq 1$. Show also, that if $\phi_t$ is the flow generated by $V$, then
$f(\phi_1(x))\leq f(x)-1$ for all $x\in M$ such that $\phi_1(x)$ exists.

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ a Riemannian metric, and $Y= \nabla f$ the graient defined by $g(\nabla f, U)= df(U)$. Then $df(Y)  =<\nabla f, \nabla f> >0$. Let $X= {Y\over <\nabla f, \nabla f> }$, then $df(X)=1$. If $\phi _t$ denote its flow, $d/dt(f\circ \phi _t)= 1$, so if this flow is defined untill the time $t$ at some point $x$, $f\circ \phi _t (x)-f(x)=t$, in particular $f(\phi _1(x))= 1+f(x)$.

Remark : your sign $-$ should be a $+$: consider the the example $f(x)=x$ in dimension 1), $V= {d\over dx}$, $\phi _t(x)=x+t$